# URL Rewriting in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a couple of questions with regards to implementing URL Rewriting in Visual Studio 2008

- I am currently using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter to implement URL rewriting in CS 2008. However the rewrite rules are a little different as compared to the IIS7 rewrite rules.Is there a way we can use the same rules while debugging in VS2008 and then employ the same rules while using on IIS7.
- What is the best way to ignore images, css and js files from the rewriting rules.Is this possible with Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.
- Are there any better methods?

  Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Kushal,

Yeah you could do a couple of things. Personally I would pick one and stick with it. If you want to go Intelligencia, then your rules will work in the built-in debugger as well as IIS7 in Integrated Mode. If you want to use the rewrite rules extension, then install it in your local IIS7 http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite, then setup a new website in your local IIS pointing to the web root of your project. Edit your hosts file and point the domain host header of your site to your local IP.  You can edit the properties for your web project and select Custom Server for your debugger and paste the host header for your local site in there. This way you're running IIS7 for dev and prod.

For ignoring static files like js and css from the Intelligencia use this rule at the top of your rule list:

```
<rewrite url="^(/.+(\.gif|/.+\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js|\.asmx|\.axd|\.flv|\.swf)(\?.+)?)$" to="$1" processing="stop" />
```

The only other thing I can think of is to setup a post-build task that would run a script to read Intelligencia rules, then convert and write them as IIS rewite rules.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using URL Rewrite for that, http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite and for development use IIS Express ( http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-developer-express-overview/ ) which comes with URL Rewrite integrated and you can set up and use it with VS 2008, see: [How to configure Visual Studio 2008 to use IIS Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682727/how-to-configure-visual-studio-2008-to-use-iis-express)

The best thing is that you will have all the features (not only URL Rewrite), like Request Filtering, Failed Request TRacing, etc, that you will have when you deploy to the server and be completely ready to deploy.