# How to configure Visual Studio 2008 to use IIS Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-express

The [IIS Express FAQ](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/) notes that:

> You can also manually launch IIS
>   Express from the command line and use
>   it with Visual Studio 2008, using the
>   custom web server option

How do I configure the Start Options to get this working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I configure IIS Express to run with VS2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326530/how-do-i-configure-iis-express-to-run-with-vs2008)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following seems to work for IIS Express launching from the command line:

1. Open the `Properties` for the web site
2. Select `Start Options`
3. Under Start Action select `Start External Program`, put the path to `iisexpress.exe` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`)
4. Command Line Arguments: /path:{path to the project solution} /clr:3.5
5. Under `Server`, select `Use Custom Server`
6. Base Url: `http://localhost:8080/` (the default for IIS Express)
7. **Important!** Uncheck everything under `Debuggers` otherwise you'll get an error "Unable to start debugging on the web server.

Information on launching using a config file can be found at this site: [Debug Your .NET Web Project With IIS Express [Tips & Tricks]](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225064636/http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2010/7/11/debug-your-net-web-project-with-iis-express-t.aspx).  This is VS2010 specific but I suspect the same will work for 2008.

Comment: I've got this working on Visual Studio 2008 as per your instructions but do you know how I can get HTTPS working as well?

Comment: Note that this requires Service Pack 1 of Visual Studio 2008.  Otherwise the "Use Custom Web Server" option is not available.