# Can I use IIS Express with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, iis-express

I want to know if it possible to use IIS express with Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: It's specific to 2008 but you might want to try this and see if you can tailor it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682727/how-to-configure-visual-studio-2008-to-use-iis-express