# How to get rid of command line window when starting IISExpress?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, iis-express

Is there a chance to get rid of command line window when starting IISExpress (iisexpress.exe)?
In the thread [Use IIS Express in visual studio 2010 without sp1 and command window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343714/use-iis-express-in-visual-studio-2010-without-sp1-and-command-window) is determined, that it is not possible with a parameter of iisexpress.exe itself.

Are there any tricks with batch scripting or something like that?

I want to start IISExpress with a .bat file, but then the command windows should hide itself (because stopping the server is also possible with the tray icon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a few ways to solve this.
One way is a Windows Script, see [Duncan Smart's Weblob](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/03/10/running-iisexpress-without-a-console-window/) or directly his [GIT-Repository](https://gist.github.com/864322).

Another way is to build a Windows Form Application (or similar), and use the [ProcessStartInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx), which offers the [ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) property.

What I did at last: I dropped IIS Express and switched to [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/). It is a great webserver (amongst others available as console application and DLL-assembly) which allowed me to build be ["self-hosted"](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20CassiniDev%20to%20host%20ASP.Net%20in%20your%20application&referringTitle=Documentation) website by importing a single DLL.

Answer (score 3):

Using PowerShell:

```
Start-Process .\iisexpress.exe -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Comment: Tested on Windows 10 Pro with this command. IISExpress.exe was hidden at background (within the PowerShell boundary as shown in task manager).