# How do i prevent from many asp.net development iis to be open?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a solution ( sln) with many console applications and 6 web sites.

but when I'm debugging one project , the VS opens 6 different IIS icons ( asp.net server) .

I want them to use only one icon.

how do I do it ?

[image]

Comment: If it helps, host the websites directly in IIS. You would still be able to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> VS provides an explicit setting in the property grid of web application/site called Development Web Server - "Always Start When Debugging" which is set to True by default... If you set this Property to be False only one web server instance will be created for the start` up web project.

- [Preventing multiple Visual Studio Development Servers from starting](http://blog.geocortex.com/2010/06/04/always-start-when-debugging-preventing-multiple-visual-studio-development-servers-from-starting/)
- [Start-Up Options and Instances of ASP.Net Development Server in a Multi-project Solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/12/24/tips-tricks-start-up-options-and-instances-of-asp-net-development-server-in-a-multi-project-solution.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/520/microsoft-web-platform/). This will only place a single item in the Notification Area. It integrates well with Visual Studio 2010; but there are some [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682727/how-to-configure-visual-studio-2008-to-use-iis-express) to get it to work with Visual Studio 2008 or less.